# Json file output is [null, null, null, null]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm trying to save and output some data from my website but when I check my movies.json file it shows,

```
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
```

That's a null for every ID in my database.

This is the log from the Rails server,

```
Started GET "/movies.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-25 07:52:48 +0200
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by MoviesController#index as JSON
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Movie Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies"
Completed 200 OK in 116ms (Views: 10.1ms | ActiveRecord: 4.5ms)
```

In my application_controller.rb I have

```
respond_to :html, :json
```

My movies_controller.rb

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    respond_with Movie.all
  end

  def create
    respond_with Movie.create(movie_params)
  end

  private
  def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title)
  end

end
```

My movie.rb model,

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

  def as_json(options = {})
  end

end
```

If I check `Movie.all` in my Rails console I do see all the correct values, so it's not outputting right in the JSON output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overwriting `as_json` with an empty implementation which returns nothing.

If you actually need to overwrite the default serializer, you have to specify the fields you want serialized

```
def as_json(options = {})
 { :username => username, :name => first_name + " " + last_name }
end
```

If the default implementation is enough for you, just remove

```
def as_json(options = {})
end
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, the reason for this mistake was that I followed a tutorial that showed `def as_json(options = {})
   super(options.merge(include: :comments))
  end` I just removed the merge part. Dumb mistake. Thank you for the quick response and clear answer.